# Get an operationContext channel by SessionID

Tags: wcf, sessionid

I'm looking for a way to aquire a specific wcf ContextChannel (or an OperationContext) by it's SessionId.
I saved the 'OperationContext.Current.Channel.SessionId', and now i want to get this channel by the SessionID. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. OperationContext is only available for the duration of a call. How WCF constructs/manages them internally is not something you can or should rely upon.

If you wish to have state associated with a session you should either use PerSession server instancing and store your state in the service instance OR store that state externally and use the OperationContext.Current.SessionId as the key.